# On-demand Texture Loading with GLKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I have an application in which I need to draw text on the screen using OpenGL textures. In my render loop I request the textures from my TextureController, which has functions such as

```
- (GLuint)textureForImageNamed:(NSString*)fileName;
{
    // we're checking a hash.. possibly slow
    NSNumber* textureHandle = [textures objectForKey:fileName]; 

    if(!textureHandle)
        textureHandle = [self loadTexture:fileName];

    GLuint handle = (GLuint)[textureHandle unsignedIntValue];

    return handle;
}
```

where loadTexture loads the texture into memory like this

```
- (NSNumber*)loadTexture:(NSString*)fileName
{
    GLuint texID = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:
                    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] CGImage] 
                                                options:nil 
                                                  error:nil].name;
    NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:texID];
    [textures setObject:num forKey:fileName];

    return num;
}
```

And similar functions for text:

```
- (GLuint)textureForTextWithString:(NSString*)text;
- (NSNumber*)loadTextureForString:(NSString*)text;
```

This all works fine when I have requested the image once before my render loop, but the whole point is that the text and images that need to be drawn are not known in advance. So I want to be able to call `textureForTextWithString:@"fooBar"` and either give me the texture if it was loaded before, or load it in -- add it to the dictionary and then give it to me. However, I get a black texture for all the textures that weren't preloaded (i.e. for which `textureForTextWithString:@"fooBar"` was not called before I started the render loop).

Relevant code in the render loop:

```
GLuint secondTex = [textures textureForTextWithString:@"NO"];    
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, secondTex);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, some_vertex_buffer);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, num);
```

I am looking for a solution, or better yet -- advice on how to better handle this particular problem.

**EDIT**: The two files in question can be found here:

- https://gist.github.com/3153940 - The main OpenGL VC
- https://gist.github.com/3153941 - The texture controller